# Find the CDF on a circular target

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

I am trying the find the solution to problem **7 b)** from Bertsekas, "Introduction to probability".
My problem is that I cannot get the CDF of $s = (\frac{1}{t} , \infty)$ (the 1st interval below) correctly

[image]

here is my attempt...

[image]

The prominent values that the random variables X and $S = \frac{1}{X}$ can split into two intervals as:

$x = (0 ,  t)   $
$\rightarrow$
$S = (1/t , \infty)$

$x = (t  ,  r)$
$\rightarrow$
$S = (0 , 1/t)$

It is illustrated below.

[image]

For the 2nd interval 
$x = (t  ,  r)$
$\rightarrow$
$S = (0 , 1/t)$

$P(S < s) = P(1/X < 1/t) = P(X > t) = 1 - P(X < t) = 1 - \frac{\pi\times t^2}{\pi\times r^2} = 1 - \frac{t^2}{r^2}$

[image]

Now for the 1st interval $x = (0 ,  t)   $
$\rightarrow$
$S = (1/t , \infty)$

$P(S > s) = P(S > \frac{1}{t}) = P(\frac{1}{X} > \frac{1}{t}) = P(X < t) = \frac{\pi \times x^2}{\pi \times r^2} $

using the definition $S = \frac{1}{X}$

$P(S > s) = \frac{1}{(sr)^2}$

Does this mean for 1st interval $ \frac{1}{t}< s < \infty$

$F(s) = P(S < s) = 1 - \frac{t^2}{r^2} + \frac{1}{(sr)^2}$

This is illustrated below

[image]

I know that this is not correct because F(s) should be monotonically increasing and reach 1 as S tends to infinity.

I dont understand the solution from the book given below.
[image]

[image]

Please help to explain to me.

Thanks.

Comment: Could someone please explain the need for total probability theorem above in the answers?

What is the meaning of $P(S <= s | X > t) = 1$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bit of sloppy writing, but I'm ignoring this as at the end you come the right conclusions.

For $s > \frac1t$, you correctly come to the conclusion that $P(S > s)=\frac1{s^2r^2}$ Since for $s > \frac1t$ $S$ is continuous, that means $P(S = s) = 0$, so consequently
$P(S < s)=1-\frac1{s^2r^2}$, because all those probabilities needs to add up to $1$, which gives the solutuion presented in the book.

Your error is in dragging the term $-\frac{t^2}{r^2}$ into this, which has no basis.

Comment: Thanks Ingix for your concise answer. 
Just to clarify: Each interval is considered separately. For example, for the first interval  $x = (0 ,  t) \rightarrow S = (1/t , \infty)$ $P(S < s)$ refers to probability values in  $(\frac{1}{t} <s < \infty)$ interval only. I was confusing with accumulating probabilities as in the F(S), CDF calculation for larger s values.

Comment: Also if I had done $P(S < s)$ for the first interval 
$ P(S < s) = P(S < \frac{1}{t}) = P(\frac{1}{X} < \frac{1}{t}) = P(X > t) = \frac{\pi \times r^2 - \pi \times x^2}{\pi \times r^2} $ and then using the definition $S = \frac{1}{X}$ I could get $1 - \frac{1}{(sr)^2}$